# Could someone summarize what this cookie/form redirect is doing?

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, redirect

I'm not familiar with this type of redirect and am puzzled as to what it's doing exactly.

It appears when I view the source(as opposed to inspect element) of certain advertisers pages while using the chrome browser, after having clicked their ad(going through the ad platform redirect + advertiser's tracker redirect). The g_gbc goback var is a random(seems to be) 7 digit number. If I copy the code to a new page on my site, a redirect loop occurs when visiting.

```
<html>
<head><title>Redirecting...</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
var g_gbc = "goback_521653";
function doClick()
{
if (getCookie(g_gbc) == "1")
{
    setCookie(g_gbc, "2");
    window.history.back();
}
else if (getCookie(g_gbc) == "2")
{
    setCookie(g_gbc, "1");
    window.history.forward();
}
else
{
    setCookie(g_gbc, "1");
    document.c.submit();
}
}

function setCookie(name, value)

{
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value);
}

function getCookie(name)
{
var dc = document.cookie;
var prefix = name + "=";
var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
if (begin == -1)
{
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
}
else
{
    begin += 2;
}
var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
if (end == -1)
{
    end = dc.length;
}
return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}

function deleteCookie(name)
{
if (getCookie(name))
{
    document.cookie = name + "=" + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
}
}
-->
</script>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="doClick();">
<form name="c" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="destination" name="destination" value="http://same-url-as-current-destination">
<noscript>
<input type="submit" value="Click here to go to the website">
</noscript>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's time you got introduced to local & session storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code hides the true source of traffic from the people running the destination site.

1. A user clicks on a link on PageA which goes to PageB (this code).
2. PageB (this code) immediately sends the browser to PageC (the "destination" value in the form).
3. If the user clicks [Back] while viewing PageC, the browser goes to PageB (this code) but it immediately detects this and sends the browser back once more to PageA (the original page).
4. The user can continue clicking forward and back from PageA through PageB to PageC without ever actually stopping on or seeing PageB (this code).
5. The people who run the web server for PageC will only get HTTP referrer headers that indicate the user came from PageB.  The owners of PageC never know what the URL is of PageA so they don't know from where their traffic originates.